# GDB doesn't see source files other than main, caused by makefile?

Tags: c, debugging, makefile

I have a semi-large project that I am trying to debug and for some reason gdb is only willing to show the source code of the `main.c` file and refuses to list any of the other files.

Here are the relevant lines in my makefile:

```
DEFINES= #...
BASE_CFLAGS= #...
BASE_LIBS= #...

#Load the required source files
HEADERS=$(wildcard *.h) $(wildcard subdir/*.h)  
SOURCES=$(HEADERS:.h=.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

#Flags for each compilation type
CFLAGS=-Wall $(DEFINES)
main: CFLAGS+=$(BASE_CFLAGS) $(BASE_LIBS)
debug: CFLAGS+=$(BASE_CFLAGS) $(BASE_LIBS) -g -DDEBUG_MODE 

#Compilation rules for objects
%.o: %.c %.h
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

#main compilation
main:$(OBJECTS) main.c
    $(CC) main.c $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) -o ../main.out 

#debug compilation
debug:$(OBJECTS) main.c
    $(CC) main.c $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) -o ../debug.out 

clean:
    rm $(OBJECTS)
```

For some reason when I run `make debug` then try to debug the resulting output it acts as though `main.c` is the only file compiled with the `-g` flag even though I ran `make clean` beforehand and inspected make's output to ensure that it did compile each object with the `-g` flag.

Before my most recent change I had a Makefile that looked more like this:

```
DEFINES= #...
BASE_CFLAGS= #...
BASE_LIBS= #...

#Load the required source files
HEADERS=$(wildcard *.h) $(wildcard subdir/*.h)  
SOURCES=$(HEADERS:.h=.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

#main compilation
main:$(SOURCES) main.c
    $(CC) $(SOURCES) main.c -Wall $(DEFINES) $(BASE_CFLAGS) $(BASE_LIBS) -o ../main.out

#debug compilation
debug:$(SOURCES) main.c
    $(CC) $(SOURCES) main.c -Wall $(DEFINES) $(BASE_CFLAGS) $(BASE_LIBS) -g -DDEBUG_MODE -o ../debug.out
```

Which was obviously less efficient than my new solution but it did have a few advantages. Firstly I didn't have to run `make clean` between each main and debug compilation (I actually have a total of 8 different compilation rules, so having to clean between most of them to get the individual sources to be recompiled with the new options is a pain). Secondly and most importantly, GDB was able to see all of the source files when I ran the debug compilation. Now, as I said, it can only see main.c and lists the rest as "No source file named ???.c".

Therefore I have two questions:

1. (not really important) Is there a way to compile each source independently, but force them to be recompiled with new options when a different compilation rule is selected in make.
2. (very important, please help!) Why can't gdb see my other source files and what can I do to have it load them?

Comment: `debug: CFLAGS+=$(BASE_CFLAGS) $(BASE_LIBS) -g -DDEBUG_MODE ` - does this actually work? I would think that it would simply make the target "debug" depend on all of those (non-existent) files.

Comment: Yep, its called target-specific variable assignment. I've found it very useful: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Comment: @n.m. "There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites, etc."

Comment: Is the line starting with `$(CC)` supposed to be indented?

Comment: @immibis hm, indeed, missed that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that line is supposed to be indented. Something went wrong when I copied it over to SO, but it **is** indented in the real makefile.

Comment: Check the size difference in object files w/wo debug. Or use `objdump` to examine the files. They must have debug symbols included. How do you know gdb does not see the other files? How did you try? Also, your Makefile fails when you'll have `main.h` one day :).

Comment: I checked the difference and there is a large size discrepancy. One example file was 27416 bytes when compiled for debugging but only 15872 bytes when compiled for release. I tried `objdump -t` on some of the files and there seem to be many symbols in there. I tested in gdb by running `list file.c:0` and on all files except main.c I got the message: `No source file named file.c` It seems like for some reason the executable stripped the symbols of the object files that were used to make it, but not the main symbols.

Comment: @LambdaBeta I've tried it and it works for me. Unless you do call `strip` symbols must be included. Anyway, try to compile all sources independently (including main.c) and link them in one step without compiling any additional file.

Answer (score 0):

the following makefile can be invoked with `make` or with `make -Ddebug` depending on if you want to produce the `main.out` file or the `debug.out` file.

Note: the `<tab>` will need to be replaced with an actual tab char in your makefile

```
CC := /usr/lib/gcc
RM := /usr/lib/rm

ifndef debug
target := main.out
debugInfo :=
else
target := debug.out
debugInfo := -g -DDEBUG_MODE
endif

#Load the required source files
HEADERS=$(wildcard *.h) $(wildcard subdir/*.h)
SOURCES=$(HEADERS:.h=.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

#Flags for each compilation type
CFLAGS+= $(debugInfo) -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu99

.PHONY : all
all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):$(OBJECTS)
<tab>$(CC) $(debugInfo) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

#Compilation rules for objects
%.o:%.c %.h
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY : clean
clean:
<tab>$(RM) $(OBJECTS)
```